Телеграм бот. Python. Нужна помощь!
Цель - человек вводит в телеграме /generate {слово} и должна выдаваться картинка.
Выводит ошибку и очень много символов.
Все токены верны. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить!
import json 
import time 
import requests 

import telebot 
# Установите свой токен бота 
TOKEN = 'мой токен' 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) 
 
class Text2ImageAPI: 
    def __init__(self, url, api_key, secret_key): 
        self.URL = url 
        self.AUTH_HEADERS = { 
            'X-Key': f'Key {api_key}', 
            'X-Secret': f'Secret {secret_key}', 
        } 
 
    def get_model(self): 
        response = requests.get(self.URL + 'key/api/v1/models', headers=self.AUTH_HEADERS) 
        data = response.json() 
        return data[0]['id'] 
 
    def generate(self, prompt, model, images=1, width=512, height=512): 
        params = { 
            "type": "GENERATE", 
            "numImages": images, 
            "width": width, 
            "height": height, 
            "generateParams": { 
                "query": f"{prompt}" 
            } 
        } 
 
        data = { 
            'model_id': (None, model), 
            'params': (None, json.dumps(params), 'application/json') 
        } 
        response = requests.post(self.URL + 'key/api/v1/text2image/run', headers=self.AUTH_HEADERS, files=data) 
        data = response.json() 
        return data['uuid'] 
 
    def check_generation(self, request_id, attempts=10, delay=10): 
        while attempts > 0: 
            response = requests.get(self.URL + 'key/api/v1/text2image/status/' + request_id, headers=self.AUTH_HEADERS) 
            data = response.json() 
            if data['status'] == 'DONE': 
                return data['images'] 
 
            attempts -= 1 
            time.sleep(delay) 
 
api = Text2ImageAPI('https://api-key.fusionbrain.ai/', 'токен', 'секретный токен') 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['generate']) 
def generate_image(message): 
    model_id = api.get_model() 
    uuid = api.generate("Sun in sky", model_id) 
    images = api.check_generation(uuid) 
    if images: 
        for image_url in images: 
            # Скачиваем изображение 
            print(image_url) 
            response = requests.get(image_url) 
            # Отправляем изображение пользователю 
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, response.content) 
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Image generation failed.") 
 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Вот ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/images/main.py", line 69, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1178, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1253, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1215, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 8449, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "/home/runner/images/main.py", line 62, in generate_image
    response = requests.get(image_url)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 575, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 367, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/home/runner/images/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 438, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema( {гигантское кол-во символов})


текст ошибки к вопросу прикрепить не хотите?

уже созвонился с гадалкой, говорит через 3 рабочих дня пришлет нам текст ошибки, ура!

добавил, извините

А что print(image_url) говорит перед тем как ошибка возникает? Там просто лежит что-то без http:// в начале.

https:// вроде есть. А print(image_url) выводит очень много символов, как я понял картинки

Погодите, так print(image_url) выводит https://... или нет? Это должен быть валидный URL, в противном случае requests.get(image_url) даст именно такую ошибку, которую вы и наблюдаете.

print(image_url) не выводит https://..., а выводит очень много символов

Значит в image_url не URL, а может быть сама картинка готовая, такое бывает. Вам нужно сообразить, что с этим делать. Отсылать запрос requests в этом случае явно не нужно.

Потребовалось использовать base64 и всё. Оказалось, что эту кучу символов надо раскодировать
